# Android development view pager show on widget

Tags: android-widget

> I want shown view pager on widget.Previously i used android list at
>   widget but i want to show only        single item on widget view this
>   is change on swipe.   please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **[AdapterViewFilper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterViewFlipper.html)** - Simple `ViewAnimator` that will animate between two or more views that have been added to it. Only one child is shown at a time. If requested, can automatically flip between each child at a regular interval. - [Example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGf_eftjxD4%E2%80%8E)

And you can use:

Starting with API level 11 (Android 3.0.x) you can use "`android.widget.RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory`" and and assign a widget to use (from docs):

**ListView**: A view that shows items in a vertically scrolling list. For an example, see the Gmail app widget.

**GridView**: A view that shows items in two-dimensional scrolling grid. For an example, see the Bookmarks app widget.

**StackView**: A stacked card view (kind of like a rolodex), where the user can flick the front card up/down to see the previous/next card, respectively. Examples include the YouTube and Books app widgets.

See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html section Using App Widgets with Collections.